# Why is foo & bar not returning true on comparison? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to make a comparison. When a user first clicks the document name, that name should be stored as a variable. When the user adds or subtracts to the name, then something will happen. (Unless the name is returned to the original name; stored in the variable).

The two variables don't appear to be equal, or I'm using the wrong comparison and I'm not sure how to achieve this.

My Markup:

```
<td class="document-name" contenteditable="true"><?= str_replace('_',' ',$document->name); ?> </td>
```

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.document-name').keyup(function(){
        var bar=$(this).html().replace(/&nbsp;/g,'');
        var foo=$(this).data("oldName");
        console.log("oldName is:" + foo);
        console.log("Bar is:" + bar);
        if(foo===bar){
          console.log("foo and bar are the same")
        }
      }).click(function(){
        $(this).data("oldName",$(this).html().replace(/&nbsp;/g,''));
      });
    });
```

Comment: You should probably [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) foo and bar. If it's not enough, test `console.log(foo, bar)` to have a better look.

Comment: What shows up in the `console.log()` output?